# "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 295 of the JSON data"

Tags: javascript, php, json, mysqli

Im making a list with gyms, with their names,image, team, spots, cp, owner, id, lat, lon.

Now i have it that it gets every query etc. but it gives now many same ids, images, team, etc. but it needs to show all mon_cp mon_owner, mon_id because those mon_* are all different each time.

also it show me the error: "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 295 of the JSON data"

```
    $sql = "SELECT 
f.id, f.lat, f.lon, f.name, f.url, d.fort_id, d.pokemon_id, d.owner_name, d.cp, s.fort_id, s.team, s.slots_available
FROM forts AS f
LEFT JOIN gym_defenders AS d ON f.id=d.fort_id
LEFT JOIN fort_sightings AS s ON f.id=s.fort_id ORDER BY last_modified DESC";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $url = preg_replace("/^http:/i", "https:", $row['url']);

    if($row['team'] == 1){ $team = "mystic";}
    if($row['team'] == 2){ $team = "valor";}
    if($row['team'] == 3){ $team = "instinct";}

        $encode = array("id" => $row['id'],
            "name" => $row['name'],
            "image" => $url,
            "team" => $team,
            "spots" => $row['slots_available'],
            "mon_cp" => $row['cp'],
            "mon_owner" => $row['owner_name'],
            "mon_id" => $row['pokemon_id'],
            "lat" => $row['lat'],
            "lng" => $row['lon']);

        echo json_encode($encode, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
}
```

it needs to output the following:

name: Gymname

image: https://images.com/image.png

team: valor

mon_cp: 1234, 233

mon_owner: monowner2000,monowner232

mon_id: 150, 155

lat: 34.67854

lon: 5.054567

Comment: You are `echo`-ing a complete JSON object each iteration of your result-set. This will make the response invalid

Comment: how should i handle it then because if i echo it below the } of the while loop it only shows 1 item. @Phil

Answer (score 1):

You are `echo`-ing a complete JSON object each iteration of your result-set. This will make the response invalid.

Simply move

```
echo json_encode($encode); // note, do NOT use JSON_FORCE_OBJECT
```

outside the `while` loop and change the `$encode` assignment to a push...

```
$encode[] = ['id' => ...
```

This will result in an array response.

Comment: That makes my errors go indeed away but it shows me now so many items look how my example output needs to be. It gives now hundreds of items with the same info. they only need other values to it when they have more so you have a list in one. like mon_owner: monowner2000, monowner3

Comment: @PrizenTV sorry, you're not making much sense. If your query returns too many results, then you should change it to only return the data you want

Comment: at my point it only needs to show 7 items because i have only 7 gyms, but it gives me 9999 items.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/VyaIG you see same id's only some of them have different mon_* values, those needs to be in 1. in the image you see many id: 5 and 1 id: 9.

Comment: @PrizenTV seems your database has duplicate values then. That and/ or your `gym_defenders` and / or `fort_sightings` tables are *many-to-one* with `forts` in which case, getting repeated `forts` values is expected when using joins

Comment: there are no duplicate values but it needs to show like this: http://pogomap.frl/include/data.php?id=gyms

But needs to show something like this: https://pastebin.com/2q4FfNxT